# Why is there a visual indicator at the top of the screen when using a Cmd-shortcut on OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I've noticed that on OSX, when you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, for instance, the `File` part will be highlighted for a fraction of a second, as do the other buttons when using a shortcut with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Is this a UI decision or is there a technical reason behind this?

Comment: That's the menu containing the item this keyboard shortcut refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter a keyboard shortcut, the corresponding menu that would contain that command lights up. For example, if you did a `Copy` using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the `Edit` menu lights up. After doing some research, this is just simply by design, with no huge technical reason behind it.

Comment: Oh, so there isn't any deeper reason to this behaviour beyond simple design, I see. Thank you!